# BGE - How do I make an sound stop when pressing a key, then start again when releasing it?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, audio

Basically, I have an airplane and an engine sound. What I'm trying to do is have a steady sound when flight is normal (always -and- motion, speed 5) then change the pitch when I speed up or slow down by pressing certain keys. Like, <kbd>Shift</kbd> adds 2.5 and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> subtracts 2.5 from the speed.
I can easily make the sound change when I press a key, (keyboard -and- sound, changed pitch). But the problem with that, is the original sound for normal speed still plays.

So basically, is there a way to cut the idle sound when pressing a key, then playing it again when said key is released?

This is what I have of my game so far, just so you know what I'm getting at.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wk_ILaMoX6M

[image: logic bricks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the logic in place to disable the original sound.

[image]

Rather than using an always sensor to activate the normal sound,use a **Nand** or **Nor** controller attached to the original keypress that plays the second sound. If this still doesn't work, activate **TRUE** and **False level triggering** which will make the sensor activate (and deactivate, respectively).

These are the two little buttons, each containing 3 dots, on the sensor.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Basically just 2 keyboards, 3 controllers (2 ands and a nor) and 3 sounds. The nor is connected to both kebyoards, and only one of the 3 sounds! Then both keyboards are marked false. This helped me a lot, and I'm describing in detail what I did that works for anyone else searching for the same! THANK YOU AGAIN!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Don't be shy if you have any more questions :)